# Running my postman collections in Azure devops pipelines gives me a warning that NO html test results report file is found

Tags: postman, azure-pipelines-build-task, npm-publish

I am running my postman collections in Azure devops pipelines, runs well but i get a warning  "##[warning]No test result files matching **/*.xml were found" in the Publish Rest Results. Another issue is that Test tab is missing in the test summary. Could i be missing something in my scripts?

My YAML is as follows:

pool:
name: Azure Pipelines
demands: npm

steps:

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom'
  inputs:
  command: custom
  verbose: false
  customCommand: 'install -g newman'
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Install html report'
  inputs:
  command: custom
  verbose: false
  customCommand: 'install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra'
- script: |
  echo $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  dir
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
- script: |
  **newman run ./PostmanCollection.json -g ./GlobalVariables.json -e ./EnvironmentVariables.json -r htmlextra --reporters cli,junit.json.htmlextra  --reporter-junit-export-junitReport.xml --reporter-htmlextra-export TestReport.html**

  displayName: 'Run API Test With Report'
  continueOnError: true
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results '
  inputs:
  testResultsFiles: '**/*.xml'
  mergeTestResults: true
  testRunTitle: Results

Comment: That script doesn't look right, you have an extra `-r` flag which isn't needed because you're also using `--reporters`. The export flag for the junit reporter isn't right either, you have included the file location in the flag.

Comment: @DannyDainton I have tried omitting **-r htmlextra** that comes before **--reporters**, but it's not working. I'm not sure i understand what i should change on export flag.

Comment: `--reporter-junit-export-junitReport.xml` is not right `--reporter-junit-export junitReport.xml` is what it should be. Also, this isn't right `cli,junit.json.htmlextra` why is there a dot there?

Comment: I do not get the difference.

Comment: This is the first time i'm learning this, should it be a comma in between the cli, json, htmlextra?

Comment: I changed the dot with a comma and it worked well. Thank you @DannyDainton.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your questions, but may be a better solution.
Postman released their CLI which is similar to Newman and has built-in integrations and reporting
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman-cli/postman-cli-overview/